# Is subversion 1.7 ok on CentOS 5.9 ? Or is 1.6 the latest stable?

Tags: svn, centos

My friend just asserted to me that:

> version 1.6.13 of subversion is the latest stable one for CentOS 5.9

What do you experts think? Does subversion 1.7 run fine on CentOS 5.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion 1.6/1.7/1.8 run fine and can be installed as clients/run via svnserve/run as mod_dav_svn on Redhat 5/6 or Centos 5/6.

If you are running a server, compile and run 1.8 latest for most features, least disk space and network usage. Client wise, it generally doesn't matter which version, although 1.7 clients have better merge capabilities connecting to 1.7+ servers.

Comment: thanks a lot for that electrawn.  regarding 1.8 svnserve; unfortunately for the client we are using Versionsapp.  it is excellent for 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 svnserve, but unfortunately they have not yet supported 1.8 svnserve.  So I have to stick with 1.7 as the server.  (I understand that a 1.7 client won't work with a 1.8 server.)  however thanks for explaining to me that 1.8 is best! thanks again

Comment: 1.7 client will work fine on a 1.8 server. 1.8 client will not work on a 1.7 working copy.